# Are Google App Engine (java) service classes Thread-Safe?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is it okay to obtain a reference to a service from factory once and use it for handling multiple requests? It can be best explained using following pseudo-code for a servlet:

```
SomeServlet...{
  MemcacheService memcacheService = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
  UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
  DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

  doGet(...){
    userService.doSomething(...);
  }
...
}
```

It may be a premature optimization but i am just curious to know what is the cost of obtaining service for each request. Please share your insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the google group thread http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/d3f1536084f59c22, Ikai Lan (from the GAE team at Google) says MemcacheService is thread-safe, but that caching it is not useful, because there is just one object allocation each time you get the service from the factory.

Since all the services are obtained in a similar way, I think we could assume that they all follow the same design and are all thread-safe. But since it isn't costly to get a new instance at each query, I wouldn't cache them.

Answer (score 0):

In the google group thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/4Zt5IEKy_5s John Patterson indicates the DatastoreService is very lightweight, so it would be best get one from the factory and configure it at the point you need it.

Also in the same thread Jeff Schnitzer indicates that since the DatastoreService is not marked as threadsafe it would be unwise to assumn it is (or always will be).

However, some methods such as getCurrentTransaction() are documented as being thread aware (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/BaseDatastoreService), so it may be that the DatastoreService will be thread tolerant in some situations.