# Is it good practice to cache the result of DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService() and UserServiceFactory.getUserService()

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Looking at the [tutorial for Google AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore), I see code samples that always get access to the DatastoreService or the UserService through the corresponding 'Factories'. If I were writing DAO-like wrappers and convenience APIs, should they always go back to the factories for the services? Or is it OK to maintain references to those services within long-spanning, cross-user objects?

Answer (score 1):

`DatastoreService` is a pretty lightweight class that [mainly wraps a set of properties](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.java). So it should be pretty cheap to create and there is no point in caching it.

Comment: That is fair, but I still don't like allocating anything unnecessary on a per-request basis. At it's heart, I am wondering what the lifecycle and scope for service instances are meant to be.

Comment: +1 for a nice link to look at sources and docs. For whatever reason, the javadoc that shipped with the SDK was quite lacking.

Comment: That link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the question over thread safety here.

[Are Google App Engine (java) service classes Thread-Safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128106/are-google-app-engine-java-service-classes-thread-safe/41449457#41449457)

In summary: the DatatoreService class is not currently marked as threadsafe, so it may be prudent to get one from the factory each time you need one.